# Проверить и ограничить ввод от min до max JS

Tags: javascript, input, валидация

#### Описание

Пытаюсь сделать так чтобы пользователь БУКВАЛЬНО не смог вводить ничего кроме целого числа от `min` до `max`. Допустим `min - 10`, `max - 50`.

Мой вариант решения выглядит таким:

```js
class Board {
  static minWidthCells = 10;
  static maxWidthCells = 50;
  static widthCells = 25;
}

document.getElementById("input_width").value = Board.widthCells;

document.getElementById("input_width").addEventListener("input",
  function(event) {
    event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    event.target.value = Math.max(Board.minWidthCells, event.target.value);
    event.target.value = Math.min(Board.maxWidthCells, event.target.value);
  }
);
```

```css
.input {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  margin: auto 2.5px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
  border: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  caret-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  user-select: none;
  outline: none;
}

.input:hover {
  filter: invert(0.1);
}

td {
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        Ширина
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="input" id="input_width">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Главная проблема (в примере выше) в том что изменить значение можно только с помощью стрелок.

---

#### Вопрос

Хочу узнать - как подправить моё решение, чтобы можно было нормально вводить?

Потому что в моём решении если ввод больше 50, ставит 50, если ниже 10, ставит 10.

Или может подскажите более хорошее решение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно валидировать то что ввел пользователь, например, по `нажатию кнопки` или событию типа `keyUp`:

```
const handleKeyUp = event => {
   const value = event.target.value
   // ваша логика валидации ...
   // if (value >= 10 && value <= 50) {
   // } else {
   // }
}

document.querySelector("input_width").addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp)
```

Comment: `1.`Не знаю почему [ваш код](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVvsM.png) абсолютно не реагирует на изменения. `2.`Я подумал о таком решении но так спокойно можно вводить любую цифру. Нужно не только в скриптах, но и визуально получить результат от `min` до `max`.

Comment: В этом и есть суть валидации, вы проверяете полученные данные и в зависимости от того соответствуют они или нет вашим условиям реагируете на это. Например если введено значение болше чем разрешено то показвается уведомление о том какое значение максимально возможно. Добавьте условия которые Вам требуются

Comment: Хорошо. Скоро попробую ещё раз. Сейчас не перед компьютером.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте `<input type="number" min="10" max="50">`
Через атрибуты можно задать минимальное и максимальное значение.

Comment: Знаю о них и попробовал этот вариант. Как не странно во время ручного ввода эти атрибуты игнорируются.